# Reversing text in textbox when text is entered

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do make reverse of the entered string in textbox using Jquery immediately after text entered in textbox.

For example if user entered string `"Hello Man , How are you "` .

Expected output is `" uoy era woH , naM olleH"`

Here is my [try](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantnawarkhede/f2g4u/)

This fiddle working as expected when I copy and paste the string "Hello Man , How are you " , it is giving  output as `"uoy era woH , naM olleH"`

But when I tried to input one by one character it gives wrong output.

Comment: see this:http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-reverse-text-string.shtml

Comment: Why not using `blur` event?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are listening to the `input` event. This event is fired every time the user hit a key when the focus is in the input. (So when you copy/paste a text, the event is triggered only once).

You should reverse the string only when the user hit enter and an other key.

You can also listen to the `blur` event. It is fired when the input lose the focus.

Comment: or use `change` since it fires after the input is out of focus

Comment: `blur` is better i think.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, just set a delay on it so it doesn't happen as you're typing:

```
$('#here').on('input change keyup', function() 
{
    //alert($(this).val());

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(this).val($(this).val().split("").reverse().join(""));
    }, 500);
});
```

Also added change and keyup to the event listener to include C+P etc, maybe you could throw blue in there, as suggested by others on this Q.

Just realised also that this fires every time the input changes so it means the first reversal is re-reversed and then you're back to the original on every even number of input.

Can you have the output and input boxes separate to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be that your cursor is always at the end of the text, so you'll keep reversing the text as you type.

You could use a 'hack' and update a div that layers on top of your input:

http://jsfiddle.net/f2g4u/2/

```
$('#here').on('keyup', function() {
   var reverse = $(this).val().split('').reverse().join('');
    $('#display').text(reverse);
});
```